# PSQLException - Session setup failed in POSTGRESQL

Tags: postgresql, openbravo

when i run the ant command - ant compile.complete or ant install.source

i got these errors -

E:\source_code\Openbravo-3.0MP21\src-db\database\build-create.xml:77: org.postgr
esql.util.PSQLException: Protocol error. Session setup failed.
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(Connect
ionFactoryImpl.java:407)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(Conne
ctionFactoryImpl.java:108)
at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactor
y.java:66)
How can i fi
x these issue. All the details related to Postgresql databased are fine in 
Openbravo.properties file.

Listed below the exception stack trace.

> E:\source_code\Openbravo-3.0MP21>ant install.source Buildfile:
>   E:\source_code\Openbravo-3.0MP21\build.xml
>
> set.code.rev:
>
> code.rev:
>
> init:
>
> cleanSubfolders:
>
> clean:    [delete] Deleting directory
>   E:\source_code\Openbravo-3.0MP21\src-core\build\c lasses    [delete]
>   Deleting directory E:\source_code\Openbravo-3.0MP21\src-core\docs
>   [delete] Deleting:
>   E:\source_code\Openbravo-3.0MP21\src-core\lib\openbravo-co re.jar
>
> clean:    [delete] Deleting directory
>   E:\source_code\Openbravo-3.0MP21\src-trl\build\cl asses    [delete]
>   Deleting directory E:\source_code\Openbravo-3.0MP21\src-trl\docs
>   [delete] Deleting directory
>   E:\source_code\Openbravo-3.0MP21\src-trl\build\ja vasqlc    [delete]
>   Deleting: E:\source_code\Openbravo-3.0MP21\src-trl\lib\openbravo-trl
>   .jar
>
> clean:    [delete] Deleting directory
>   E:\source_code\Openbravo-3.0MP21\src-wad\build\cl asses    [delete]
>   Deleting directory E:\source_code\Openbravo-3.0MP21\src-wad\build\ja
>   vasqlc    [delete] Deleting directory
>   E:\source_code\Openbravo-3.0MP21\src-wad\docs    [delete] Deleting:
>   E:\source_code\Openbravo-3.0MP21\src-wad\lib\openbravo-wad .jar
>
> core.lib:
>
> init:
>       [mkdir] Created dir: E:\source_code\Openbravo-3.0MP21\src-core\build\classes
>
> ```
> [mkdir] Created dir: E:\source_code\Openbravo-3.0MP21\src-core\docs
> ```
>
> compile:
>       [javac] Compiling 124 source files to E:\source_code\Openbravo-3.0MP21\src-c ore\build\classes
>       [javac] E:\source_code\Openbravo-3.0MP21\src-core\src\org\openbravo\utils\Fo
>   rmatUtilities.java:31: warning: unmappable character for encoding
>   UTF-8
>       [javac]     return strIni.replace('?', 'a').replace('?', 'e').replace('?', ' i').replace('?', 'o')
>       [javac]                            ^
>       [javac] E:\source_code\Openbravo-3.0MP21\src-core\src\org\openbravo\utils\Fo
>   rmatUtilities.java:31: warning: unmappable character for encoding
>   UTF-8
>       [javac]     return strIni.replace('?', 'a').replace('?', 'e').replace('?', ' i').replace('?', 'o')
>       [javac]                                              ^
>       [javac] E:\source_code\Openbravo-3.0MP21\src-core\src\org\openbravo\utils\Fo
>   rmatUtilities.java:31: warning: unmappable character for encoding
>   UTF-8
>       [javac]     return strIni.replace('?', 'a').replace('?', 'e').replace('?', ' i').replace('?', 'o')
>       [javac]                                                                ^
>       [javac] E:\source_code\Openbravo-3.0MP21\src-core\src\org\openbravo\utils\Fo
>   rmatUtilities.java:31: warning: unmappable character for encoding
>   UTF-8
>       [javac]     return strIni.replace('?', 'a').replace('?', 'e').replace('?', ' i').replace('?', 'o')
>       [javac]
>                ^
>       [javac] E:\source_code\Openbravo-3.0MP21\src-core\src\org\openbravo\utils\Fo
>   rmatUtilities.java:32: warning: unmappable character for encoding
>   UTF-8
>       [javac]         .replace('?', 'u').replace('?', 'A').replace('?', 'E').repla ce('?', 'I').replace('?', 'O')
>       [javac]                   ^
>       [javac] E:\source_code\Openbravo-3.0MP21\src-core\src\org\openbravo\utils\Fo
>   rmatUtilities.java:32: warning: unmappable character for encoding
>   UTF-8
>       [javac]         .replace('?', 'u').replace('?', 'A').replace('?', 'E').repla ce('?', 'I').replace('?', 'O')
>       [javac]                                     ^
>       [javac] E:\source_code\Openbravo-3.0MP21\src-core\src\org\openbravo\utils\Fo
>   rmatUtilities.java:32: warning: unmappable character for encoding
>   UTF-8
>       [javac]         .replace('?', 'u').replace('?', 'A').replace('?', 'E').repla ce('?', 'I').replace('?', 'O')
>       [javac]                                                       ^
>       [javac] E:\source_code\Openbravo-3.0MP21\src-core\src\org\openbravo\utils\Fo
>   rmatUtilities.java:32: warning: unmappable character for encoding
>   UTF-8
>       [javac]         .replace('?', 'u').replace('?', 'A').replace('?', 'E').repla ce('?', 'I').replace('?', 'O')
>       [javac]
>       ^
>       [javac] E:\source_code\Openbravo-3.0MP21\src-core\src\org\openbravo\utils\Fo
>   rmatUtilities.java:32: warning: unmappable character for encoding
>   UTF-8
>       [javac]         .replace('?', 'u').replace('?', 'A').replace('?', 'E').repla ce('?', 'I').replace('?', 'O')
>       [javac]
>                         ^
>       [javac] E:\source_code\Openbravo-3.0MP21\src-core\src\org\openbravo\utils\Fo
>   rmatUtilities.java:33: warning: unmappable character for encoding
>   UTF-8
>       [javac]         .replace('?', 'U');
>       [javac]                   ^
>       [javac] 10 warnings
>
> build.jar:
>         [jar] Building jar: E:\source_code\Openbravo-3.0MP21\src-core\lib\openbrav o-core.jar
>
> build:
>
> copy.core.lib:
>        [copy] Copying 1 file to E:\source_code\Openbravo-3.0MP21\lib\runtime
>
> database.lib:
>
> init:
>
> compile:
>
> build.jar:
>         [jar] Building jar: E:\source_code\Openbravo-3.0MP21\src-db\build\lib\dbma nager.jar
>
> jar:
>        [copy] Copying 1 file to E:\source_code\Openbravo-3.0MP21\src-db\database\l ib
>
> create.database:
>
> create.database:
>
> clean.database.POSTGRE:
>
> BUILD FAILED E:\source_code\Openbravo-3.0MP21\build.xml:728: The
>   following error occurred whi le executing this line:
>   E:\source_code\Openbravo-3.0MP21\src-db\database\build-create.xml:50:
>   The follow ing error occurred while executing this line:
>   E:\source_code\Openbravo-3.0MP21\src-db\database\build-create.xml:77:
>   org.postgr esql.util.PSQLException: Protocol error.  Session setup
>   failed.
>           at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(Connect
>   ionFactoryImpl.java:407)
>           at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(Conne
>   ctionFactoryImpl.java:108)
>           at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactor
>   y.java:66)
>           at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.(AbstractJdbc2Conn
>   ection.java:125)
>           at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.(AbstractJdbc3Conn
>   ection.java:30)
>           at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.(AbstractJdbc3gC
>   onnection.java:22)
>           at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.(AbstractJdbc4Conn
>   ection.java:30)
>           at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
>           at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:393)
>           at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:267)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.JDBCTask.getConnection(JDBCTask.java:37
>   0)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.SQLExec.getConnection(SQLExec.java:940)
>
> ```
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.SQLExec.execute(SQLExec.java:612)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
> ```
>
> sorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
>   a:106)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(Single
>   CheckExecutor.java:38)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:440)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
>
> ```
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
> ```
>
> sorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
>   a:106)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(Single
>   CheckExecutor.java:38)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:440)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
>   sorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
>   a:106)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExe
>   cutor.java:41)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
>
> Total time: 5 seconds

Any would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to restart the postgresql services  and then try install.source..

**In windows:**

services-> postgresql 9.0 -> stop and start.